# Can't add remote Node Interpreter for mocha in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am running my code inside a vagrant machine. In WebStorm I can specify in the run configurations to use the vagrant nodejs interpretor:

[image]

Now I need to do the same for my mocha tests, however I am unable to add a Remote Node Interpreter in my Mocha run configurations:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK that is not currently possible.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22179 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: I suggest asking in that ticket about their current plans on implementing this (and definitely voting up on it). You may also add a bit of "motivation text" (e.g. why it's important to have such functionality these days -- e.g. "it's so common to run actual execution environment in containers as opposed to have it installed on actual host machine etc" but avoid "stupid" things like "why it's not yet implemented/what takes you so long" and alike -- it does not add any "bonus" points to the message -- quite opposite in fact).